# Catch parameter parsing exception in Spring 3.0 WebMVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I use Spring WebMVC to provide a REST API. I use methods like

`@RequestMapping("/path({id}") void getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {}` methods.

When the client incorrectly put a string instead of an integer id into the query, I get a NumberFormatException like:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dojo"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:525)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory$StringToNumber.convert(StringToNumberConverterFactory.java:1)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:420)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.SimpleTypeConverter.convertIfNecessary(SimpleTypeConverter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
```

My Question is now, how can I elegantly catch it? I know that Spring provides @ExeptionHandler annotations but I don't want to catch the NFE in general. I want to be able to catch all parsing exception in order to present a nice error message to the client.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 2):

Is that the actual exception? (it doesn't match your code example) Normally one would expect that to be wrapped in `org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException` which is probably specific enough that you could write an `@ExceptionHandler` method for it.

If that's not specific enough, you will need to forgo the Spring-Magic and just change the parameter type to String + parse it yourself.  Then you can handle it any way you like.

Comment: Yes, I expected the same but the NFE is the root exception. And I'm sorry I mixed long and int in my example.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution for your problem here http://www.coderanch.com/t/625951/Spring/REST-request-mapping-parameter-type

Just try

```
@RequestMapping("/path({id:[\\d]+}") void getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {} methods.
```

And then not valid usage will cause 404. I'm not sure if version 3.0 supports this.

Comment: Nice solution.With the current Spring 4 we use @ControllerAdvice to catch exceptions and it is very convenient.

Comment: Good solution. BTW this throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about whether this works for `@PathVaribale` or not, but generally for model binding you could use a `BindingResult` object next to your path variable and model and parsing error will be added to the `BindingResult/Errors` object.

Comment: I did some research but couldn't find a connection between PathVariable and BindingResult. Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I do this because I am an old tyme programmer, but I use `String` as the type for all `@PathVariable` and `@RequestParameter` parameters then I do the parsing inside the handler method.  This allows me to easily catch all `NumberFormatException` exceptions.

Although this is not the "Spring" way of doing this, I recommend it because it is easy for me and easy for my future offshore maintenance programmers to understand.

Comment: Up to know this looks like the preferred solution but I really don't like it (because it involved a  lot of changes). Hope there will be another solution.

Comment: The other solution is to override/write your own WebDataBinder and throw more specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

putting your comments together, I tried the following:

```
public class ValidatingAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter {

@Override
protected ServletRequestDataBinder createBinder(HttpServletRequest request, Object target, String objectName) throws Exception {
    return new ServletRequestDataBinder(target, objectName) {

        @Override
        public <T> T convertIfNecessary(Object value, Class<T> requiredType) throws TypeMismatchException {
            try {
                return super.convertIfNecessary(value, requiredType);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new ControllerException("Could not parse parameter: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T convertIfNecessary(Object value, Class<T> requiredType, MethodParameter methodParam) throws TypeMismatchException {
            try {
                return super.convertIfNecessary(value, requiredType, methodParam);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw new ControllerException("Could not parse parameter: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    };
}
```

ControllerException is a custom exception which is catched by an @ExceptionController annotated method (I use this exception in all validator classes).

Hope you like it,

Jan